# How do I integrate google search into my C# program?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a program in Visual C#.NET and I need some help.

I need it to be able to take in some text through a text box, then somehow send that text to google, and bring back the resulting URLs (not the full results, just the URLs) and then display those in my program. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class to send the query to Google and read the response.

Alternatively, use a .NET library that interacts with the Google search API, like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/) (this was just the first Google result).

There are also [`REST` libraries](http://restsharp.org/) for .NET, if you go with the newer custom search.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the [Google Web Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/) is deprecated and no longer available. However the next best thing IMO is [Google Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/cse/).